# Upgrading cmake in Yocto

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake

I'm using Yocto and struggling to update cmake. The poky version that we are using provides cmake version 3.3.1, but one of the packages that I'm building requires cmake version 3.5 or greater.

Looking at the poky git repo, the latest provides version 3.8.2. I figured that the easiest way to upgrade cmake was to include the [recipes for cmake from the current poky](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/cmake) master branch within my own meta repo, in order to override the lesser version. So I copied the cmake directory, and expected the build to continue along...

Unfortunately, the cmake recipes that I copied in aren't working. The recipes won't even load, as they throw an error, saying "docker must contain prefix as its prefix." Printing the output of the `prefix` and `docdir` variables to the console, I see that docdir is set to "`${datadir}/doc`" -- the `datadir` variable is not expanded.

In summary, the questions that I have are:

- What is the best way to upgrade cmake? Is the best way to copy in the updated recipes into my own meta repo?
- Why isn't the `datadir` variable being expanded, and how can I fix that?

Comment: I discovered why the variables weren't expanding -- the python commands in the recipe for 3.8.2 used `d.getVar("docdir")`. Changing that to `d.getVar("docdir", True)` triggered the expansion. I'm not sure why the recipe for 3.8.2 didn't set expand to True to begin with. 3.8.2 still had issues, so I switched to 3.6.1 (copying recipes from morty) and so far that is working. I'm still not sure if copying in these recipes is the best way to upgrade cmake...

Comment: getVar() default expansion was changed in a release between these two. Copying recipes like this is certainly a potential "recipe" for unique and hard to find problems. The best way of solving this is to use a recent poky that not only provides the software you need but is also maintained (but I realize you might have other constraints on this).

Comment: Maybe its easier to backport the cmake script of that package to the older cmake version than to upgrade cmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is probably happening is that the recipe for cmake 3.8.2 (2.4) is not backward compatible with the poky version from 3.3.1 (Version 1.9). The reference is [here](http://recipes.yoctoproject.org/rrs/recipedetail/165/). I guess some refactoring and important milestones happened meanwhile

The easiest way is to upgrade the whole poky folder in your ecosystem, hoping it is not breaking your other recipes.

Comment: Soon we'll be able to upgrade the whole poky folder, but for now there are other constraints preventing that. I'll go ahead and accept this answer since it solves the question of why I was having problems pulling from the latest poky version. For readers looking for answers to my other questions, refer to the discussion in the comments on my original post.

Comment: I understand the constraints. I don't know your development plan but if project is almost ready to ship, you have the possibility to make your own cmake 3.5 recipe working with older poky.